# Method 'Rows' Of Object '_Global' Failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm running VBA through ACCESS. Goal is to export queries to 20+ master excel sheets. After DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, I am attempting to edit the Excel workbooks.

I've altered the fpath names to exclude confidential info.

The first file updates correctly without issue.

The second file an error occurs at Rows(43).EntireRow.Delete, which I also added a note in the code.

The second batch of coding for file 2 I tested on it's own and it does NOT throw an error.

Am I not closing Excel correctly at the end of file 1, to allow file 2 to edit correctly? I'm lost.

```
Private Sub rmvHeaders_Click()

Dim d As String
Dim dt As Date
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xldata As Excel.Range
Dim fpath As String
Dim cpedt1 As String
Dim cpedt2 As String
Dim dt1 As Date
Dim dt2 As Date
Dim y As String
Dim strFileExists As String

'Grab Pay Date for File naming
dt = DLookup("[Date]", "[Weekly Pay Date]")
d = Format(dt, "mmddyy")

dt1 = DLookup("[Date]", "[Weekly Pay Date]")
dt1 = DateAdd("d", -8, dt)
cpedt1 = Format(dt1, "mmddyy")

dt2 = DLookup("[Date]", "[Weekly Pay Date]")
dt2 = DateAdd("d", -2, dt)
cpedt2 = Format(dt2, "mmddyy")

y = Year(dt)

'CLIENT
'Set file path to allow for data adjustments on the excel workbook
fpath = "\\hatserv5\public\2Invoices\CLIENT\CLIENT\" & y & "\week " & d & "\CLIENT" & d & ".xls"
strFileExists = Dir(fpath)
If strFileExists <> "" Then
   Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fpath)

   'Set the sheet name to each tab in the Excel
   Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets("Funding Sheet")
   With xlapp
       .Visible = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       .Workbooks.Open fpath
       xlsheet.Select
       xlsheet.Activate
       With ActiveSheet
           Rows(42).EntireRow.Delete
           Range("F42:F2000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
           End With
       End With

   Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
   With xlapp
       .Visible = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       .Workbooks.Open fpath
       xlsheet.Select
       xlsheet.Activate
       With ActiveSheet
           Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
           Range("V2:X2000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
           Range("AG2:AG2000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
           Range("AV2:BD2000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
           Range("A1:BE2000").EntireColumn.AutoFit
           End With
       End With

   Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets("Funding Sheet")
   With xlapp
       xlsheet.Select
       xlsheet.Activate
       .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
       .Quit
       End With
   End If

Set xlsheet = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xlapp = Nothing


'CLIENT
'Set file path to allow for data adjustments on the excel workbook
fpath = "\\hatserv5\public\2Invoices\CLIENT\CLIENT\" & y & "\week " & d & "\CLIENT " & d & " - Date from " & cpedt1 & " - " & cpedt2 & ".xls"
strFileExists = Dir(fpath)
If strFileExists <> "" Then
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fpath)

    'Edit unneccessary lines and formatting for accuracy of report
    '"Funding Sheet", "Small Package", etc.... these are names of tabs on the Excel file
    Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets("Funding Sheet")
    With xlapp
        .Visible = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Workbooks.Open fpath
        xlsheet.Select
        xlsheet.Activate
        With ActiveSheet
            Rows(43).EntireRow.Delete 'ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
            Range("F43:F2000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            End With
        End With
```

Comment: `With xlsheet`, `.Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete`, `.Range("V2:X2000")...` - fully qualify your `Rows` and `Range` calls (note the `.` before them!), and don't use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Also `xlsheet.Select` and `xlsheet.Activate` are unnecessary.

Comment: are you able to give me details on why the "." before them makes a difference?

Comment: It's necessary when you're using `With`, otherwise the inner `Range` and `Rows` calls don't actually reference the `With xlsheet`.